Is there a *covariant* functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Mod}_R$ with $X \mapsto R^X$?
Let $R$ be a non-trivial ring. Can we associate to every map of sets $f : X \to Y$ an $R$-linear map $$f_* : R^X \to R^Y$$ in such a way that the equations $(\mathrm{id})_* = \mathrm{id}$ and $(f \circ g)_* = f_* \circ g_*$ hold? Put differently, is there a functor $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Mod}_R$ such that $F(X) \cong R^X$ for every set $X$?
Notice that I am asking for a covariant functor; the question for a contravariant functor would of course be trivial. The question would also be trivial if, instead of taking the (possibly infinite) product $R^X$ we would take the direct sum $R^{\oplus X}$. And it is also easy to define a functor on the wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ whose morphisms are maps with finite fibers, because then the same formula as for the direct sum will work: For $f : X \to Y$ we define $f_* : R^X \to R^Y$ by $f_*(w)(y) = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} w(x)$. In particular, we can define such a functor on $\mathbf{Set}_{\text{mono}}$, the category of sets with injective maps.
I don't think that it is possible to define such a functor on all of $\mathbf{Set}$, but I don't know how to prove this. If we compose such a functor with the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod}_R \to \mathbf{Set}$, we get a non-empty set $T$ and a functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $X \mapsto T^X$. Such functors indeed exist (which was a bit surprising to me), see Finding functors $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $F(X) \cong T^X$. I have tried to lift this functor to $\mathbf{Mod}_R$ in case $R$ is a well-ordered ring, but this didn't work.
I suspect that the existence of the functor already fails for the subcategory of countable sets with surjective maps. For $R = \mathbb{Z}$ perhaps we can use the result $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$, but I am not sure. If it helps, feel free to add assumptions on $R$. For example, the case of a field $R$ is already interesting. Also, we have the closely related question if for a non-trivial group $G$ there is a functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Grp}$ mapping $X \mapsto G^X$ (again, I don't think so).
Edit. Eric Wofsey has given a proof when $R$ is a field. I am still interested what happens in general. But I am also happy to accept an answer for the case of $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

It seems unlikely. If $|Y|=1,$ it would mean there is a natural map $R^{X}\to R,$ and I can't see what that would be.

@ThomasAndrews: It's not clear at all that it has to be "natural" in any intuitive sense, though.

When $R$ is a field, at least, you can construct such a functor on the countable sets.  Start with the functor $F(X)=\operatorname{Hom}_R(R^X,R)$, which does what we want on finite sets and gives something really huge on infinite sets.  Now take the subfunctor $G$ of $F$ generated by all the values of $F$ on finite sets and $|R|^{\aleph_0}$ linearly independent elements of $F(\mathbb{N})$.  Then $G(\mathbb{N})$ will have dimension $|R|^{\aleph_0}$ and thus be isomorphic to $R^\mathbb{N}$.

(It's not clear to me whether you can generalize this to get a functor on all of $\mathbf{Set}$: for instance, you will end up needing to add some generators coming from $F(X)$ for very large sets $X$ to make sure $G(X)$ is big enough, but then how can you be sure that those generators don't add too many elements to $G(\mathbb{N})$?)

@ThomasAndrews If $R$ has a well-order and $X$ is non-empty, we could take the minimum function (which is not $R$-linear, though). That's why I tried to consider well-ordered rings. But Eric is right, since I do not require any natural transformation between the functor and something else, the construction can be wild. For a related example, there is a functor $C : \mathbf{Fld} \to \mathbf{Fld}$ that maps every field $K$ to an algebraic closure of $K$. Its construction uses transcendence bases + transfinite recursion. But there is no natural transformation $\mathrm{id} \to C$.

Such a functor exists if $R$ is a field.  First, if $R$ is finite, let $R'=\mathbb{N}$, and otherwise let $R'=R$. Fix a well-ordering on $R'\setminus\{0\}$ and let $G$ be the functor $G:\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$ such that $G(X)=R'^X$ and for $f:X\to Y$, $G(f):R'^X\to R'^Y$ is defined as follows.  If $s:X\to R'$ and $y\in Y$, then $(G(f)(s))(y)$ is the least element of $s(f^{-1}(\{y\}))$ with respect to our well-ordering on $R'\setminus\{0\}$, or $0$ if $s(f^{-1}(\{y\}))$ contains no elements of $R'\setminus\{0\}$.  (This functor $G$ is taken from the answer at Finding functors $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $F(X) \cong T^X$. )  Let $G_0$ be the subfunctor of $G$ such that $G_0(X)$ is the subset of $R'^X$ consisting of the functions with finite image.
Now let $F:\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Mod}_R$ be the free module functor, and let $H:\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Mod}_R$ be the quotient of $FG$ by $FG_0$.  Note that $H$ is trivial on finite sets and $\dim H(X)=|R'^X|=|R^X|$ when $X$ is infinite.  The functor $H\oplus F$ then has $H(X)\cong R^X$ whether $X$ is finite or infinite, since $\dim R^X=|R^X|$ if $X$ is infinite (see here for instance).
(Of course, the isomorphisms $H(X)\cong R^X$ are highly noncanonical when $X$ is infinite, and Global Choice would be required to turn $H$ into a functor with $H(X)$ literally equal to $R^X$.)

Thanks a lot! I am trying to understand your construction. But I have some issue with the dimension of $H(X)$. If $R$ is finite, then $H(X)=0$ right? But also when $X$ and $R$ are infinite, I don't see why $\dim H(X)$, namely the number of maps $X \to R$ with infinite image, should be $|R^X|$. The problematic case is $|R| \geq |X|$.

Oops, I was assuming $R$ was infinite, but if it's finite you can just replace it with a countably infinite set in the definition of $G$.  If $X$ is infinite, partition $X=X_0\sqcup X_1$ where $X_0$ is infinite and $|X_1|=|X|$.  Then you can fix any map $X_0\to R$ with infinite image, and take an arbitrary map $X_1\to R$ to get $|R^X|$ maps $X\to R$ with infinite image.
